# Angular directive: $implicit become any

Tags: angular

I have this structural directive for sharing data as local variable into html component template:

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

interface LetContext<T> {
    myLet: T;
    $implicit: T;
}

@Directive({
    selector: '[myLet]'
})
export class LetDirective<T> {
    
    private context: LetContext<T | null> = { myLet: null, $implicit: null };
    private hasView: boolean = false;

    constructor(private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, private templateRef: TemplateRef<LetContext<T>>) {}

    @Input()
    set myLet(value: T) {
        this.context.$implicit = this.context.myLet = value;
        if (!this.hasView) {
            this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef, this.context);
            this.hasView = true;
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <ng-container *myLet="(num1 + num2) as total">
    <div>
      1: {{ total }} <!-- 3 -->
    </div>
    <div>
      2: {{ total }} <!-- 3 -->
    </div>
  </ng-container> 
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  num1: number = 1;
  num2: number = 2;
}
```

Why `{{ total }}` is cast to any and not to number when I inspect into Visual Studio Coce?

Comment: You need to implement some more in your directive to tell the ivy part that you want to have a specific type. Therefor you need to implement type guard functions. Please have a look here, i guess this is an example close to yours: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8ebc946c0e7bf80d26ec8268acb4ff0af9e5c34a/packages/common/src/directives/ng_if.ts#L217

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directive needs to contain the static method `ngTemplateContextGuard` which tells the compiler the type of the rendered template

```ts
static ngTemplateContextGuard<T>(
  dir: LetDirective, ctx: unknown
): ctx is LetContext<T> { return true };
```